# Jackson Deserialisation of null value to long data type

Tags: java, json, jackson, long-integer

I have an object with a field that has long as a datatype. Now, in JSON, the value can either be an int/long or `null`. After deserialisation with Jackson, I want to check what was deserialised, for example, I want to check whether the value in JSON was null. However, one cannot check primitive data types for nulls. What should I do in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define setter like:

```
public void setX(Number n) { // check and assign here }
```

Comment: how about changing the data type to the Long object? I could then check for nulls

Comment: Yes, `Long` also works; or `Integer` if they are small enough. Even `Object` may be useful if you want other conversions. But `Long` may be the best for your specific use case.